# Virtual area around vml element

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, raphael, vml

this is my first post, so my deepest excuses if something went wrong :)

I have a little html-control to write and biggest problem is ie6-8 support. There are no alternatives to skip ie6-8 support at all :( So after searching a while, I did found Raphael and it allows me to create custom shapes defined in SVG file. I need to attach 'mouseover' event and select element on hover. Event working great but I did find BIG problems in VML hover behavior.

Code was simplified to RAW html with VML shape.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <style>v\: * { behavior:url(#default#VML); antialias: false; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message">hovered: nope</div>
    <v:oval id="oval" style="width:100px; height:75px" fillcolor="#bbb"></v:oval>

    <script>
        var messageElm = document.getElementById('message');
        var ovalElm = document.getElementById('oval');

        ovalElm.attachEvent('onmouseover', function () { messageElm.innerText = 'hovered: yep'; });
        ovalElm.attachEvent('onmouseout', function () { messageElm.innerText = 'hovered: nope'; });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you try to move mouse over oval element you can noticed that rendered shape is not same as hover shape. I mean, hover triggers 2-3px from rendered shape (not from each side).

So question is: how to disable that virtual area (if it is possible at all)?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i tried usemap;

first i create a map on a transparent png8 which covered the vml

```
    this.dom.insertAdjacentHTML("AfterBegin",'<map name="'+_id+'"></map><img id="'+_id+'" src="'+transparent.png+
        '" style="position:absolute;width:'+dom.clientWidth+';height:'+dom.clientHeight+'" />');
    var map = this.dom.getElementsByTagName('map')[0];
    this.dom.appendChild(map);
    this.map = map;
```

then get the shape attach to an area; map it;
i made poly demo only;

```
function _getMap(shape){
    this._map = this._map || {};
    if(this._map[shape.id]){

    }else if(shape.nodeName == 'shape'){
        var arrDots = shape.childNodes[0].v.match(/(\d+),(\d+)/g)
        this._map[shape.id] = _polyMap(arrDots);    
    }
    return this.map[shape.id]

}
function _polyMap(arrDots){
    var map = this.map;
    var area = document.createElement('area');
    area.setAttribute('shape',"poly");
    area.setAttribute('coords',arrDots.join(','));
    area.setAttribute('href','##');
    area.setAttribute('alt','##');
    map.appendChild(area);
}
```

then you can bind event on it;

```
function  _onIE(shape, evtname, fn){
    this._getMap(shape).attachEvent('on'+evtname, fn);
}
```